# How to append <img> as a <li> to a <ul>

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild, dom-manipulation

I've created a forEach loop that is collecting the urls of 10 gifs and I want to append them to a  I currently have in my html on line 33.
I have to display the gifs on the page.
I'm currently getting a list of the urls.
Is there a way I can have a list of images on the page keeping most of the code I currently have?
From line 55 down is my forEach loop where I am trying to appendChild.

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#search-btn");
button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const giffTitle = document.querySelector("#giffTitle").value;

  axios;
  const giffSection = document.querySelector(".giffs");
  const giffList = document.querySelector(".list");

  axios
    .get(
      `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=iVwoS0brONsmkA6sWVqHgJ9D7g2WYDmv&q=${giffTitle}&limit=10&offset=0&rating=g&lang=en`
    )
    .then((res) => {
      const giff = res.data;
      // const giffUrl = giff.data[0].embed_url;
      const giffUrl = giff.data;
      console.log(giffUrl);

      giffUrl.forEach(function(singleGiff) {
        let img = document.createElement("li");
        img.textContent = singleGiff.embed_url;
        giffList.appendChild(img);
        console.log(singleGiff.embed_url);
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.26.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPh3uwgU5qEMipS/VOmRqynnMXGGSRv+72H/N260MQeXZIK4PG48401Bsby9Nq5P5fz7hy5UGNmC/W1Z51h2GQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<h1>Giffs</h1>
<form action="">
  <label for="">Search</label>
  <input type="text" id="giffTitle" />
  <button id="search-btn">Search</button>
</form>
<iframe id="iframe" src="${giffUrl}" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<section class="giffs"></section>
<ul class="list"></ul>
```

I've edited to end to:

```
giffUrl.forEach(function (singleGiff) {
              let img = document.createElement("img");
              img.src = singleGiff.embed_url;
              let list = document.createElement("li");

              list.appendChild(img);
              giffList.appendChild(list);
              console.log(singleGiff.embed_url);
            });
```

and the output is a list of broken images.

Comment: Don't create an `li` element, and call it `img` ... Create a new `img` element, and set its `src` attribute to your image URL. Then append that to a newly created `li`, and then the `li` to your list element.

Comment: It seems to return a list of broken images

Comment: The `embed_url` value leads to an _HTML page_ like `https://giphy.com/embed/3o85xBA2qKZsoe7Cy4` - you can of course not specify an HTML document as the "source" of an image. You would need to pick one of the URLs that _directly_ refers to an image (if there even are any in there, I can't currently tell for sure.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both a new `li` and `img` element. And if you would like to present the GIF itself you should set the `src` attribute of the image to `singleGiff.images.downsized.url`.

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#search-btn");
button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const giffTitle = document.querySelector("#giffTitle").value;

  axios;
  const giffSection = document.querySelector(".giffs");
  const giffList = document.querySelector(".list");

  axios
    .get(
      `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=iVwoS0brONsmkA6sWVqHgJ9D7g2WYDmv&q=${giffTitle}&limit=10&offset=0&rating=g&lang=en`
    )
    .then((res) => {
      const giff = res.data;
      // const giffUrl = giff.data[0].embed_url;
      const giffUrl = giff.data;
      //console.log(giffUrl);

      giffUrl.forEach(function(singleGiff) {
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        let img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = singleGiff.images.downsized.url;
        li.appendChild(img);
        giffList.appendChild(li);
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.26.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPh3uwgU5qEMipS/VOmRqynnMXGGSRv+72H/N260MQeXZIK4PG48401Bsby9Nq5P5fz7hy5UGNmC/W1Z51h2GQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<h1>Giffs</h1>
<form action="">
  <label for="">Search</label>
  <input type="text" id="giffTitle" />
  <button id="search-btn">Search</button>
</form>
<iframe id="iframe" src="${giffUrl}" width="480" height="270" frameborder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<section class="giffs"></section>
<ul class="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
giffUrl.forEach(function (singleGiff) {
    let img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = singleGiff.embed_url;
    let listElement = document.createElement("li");
    listElement.appendChild(img);
    giffList.appendChild(listElement);
    console.log(singleGiff.embed_url);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily append image with help of **Template literals** and **HTML DOM insertAdjacentHTML() Method**. I hope below snippet will help you a lot.

**Reference Link:** 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertadjacenthtml.asp

```js
const button = document.querySelector("#search-btn");
button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const giffTitle = document.querySelector("#giffTitle").value;

    axios;
    const giffSection = document.querySelector(".giffs");
    const giffList = document.querySelector(".list");

    axios.get(
        `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=iVwoS0brONsmkA6sWVqHgJ9D7g2WYDmv&q=${giffTitle}&limit=10&offset=0&rating=g&lang=en`
    )
    .then((res) => {
        const giff = res.data;
        // const giffUrl = giff.data[0].embed_url;
        const giffUrl = giff.data;
        // console.log(giffUrl);
giffList.innerHTML = ''; // empty <ul> before listing
        giffUrl.forEach(function (singleGiff) {
            console.log(singleGiff)
            giffList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
                <li>
                    <img src="${singleGiff.images.downsized.url}">
                </li>
            `)
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.26.0/axios.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-bPh3uwgU5qEMipS/VOmRqynnMXGGSRv+72H/N260MQeXZIK4PG48401Bsby9Nq5P5fz7hy5UGNmC/W1Z51h2GQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    
<h1>Giffs</h1>
<form action="">
    <label for="">Search</label>
    <input type="text" id="giffTitle" />
    <button id="search-btn">Search</button>
</form>
<section class="giffs"></section>
<ul class="list"></ul>
```